# Struts 2 action class as JPA entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, struts2

I am new to Struts 2 integration with JPA/Hibernate . In Struts 2 Action class itself serve as  Pojo . Can i use same Action class as  Entity also? or what will be best practice in this scenario .

Comment: I would not advice that.  Your actions should not be your model.  Your action should 'use' the model.

Comment: S2 actions aren't exactly POJO-s. Use separate classes for you model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best scenario will be if you use action classes as actions related to web-communication and pojo as pojo for data handling =)
don't merge them

Answer (score 0):

No. See for example [Struts 2 + Spring 2 + JPA + AJAX](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html) from the apache site. Any properly designed Java EE application with have good separation of the Controller and Model layers. The Controller layer, in this case a struts action, will typically communicate to the Model through a service layer.